# How to improve search performance

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of `Country` objects that have this design:

```
public class Country
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string ISO { get; set; }
}
```

I need to check if in a particular list a `Country` exists or not, so I did:

```
foreach (var date in dates)
{
    var newCountries = GetCountryByDate(date);

    foreach (var country in newCountries)
    {
        if (!countries.Exists(c => c.ISO == country.iso))
            countries.Add(new Country
            {
                Id = country.id,
                Name = country.name,
                ISO = country.iso,
                Link = country.id.ToString()
            });
    }
}
```

where `newCountries` contains the list of `Country` which need to be iterated, and `countries` is a `List<Country>` filtered by date, infact each `date` contains a different list of `Countries`.

The problem's that this mechanism is really slow

Comment: I guess the main problem is `GetCountryByDate(date)`. can you change it by given range of dates : `countries = GetCountryByDate(fromdate,todate);`?

Comment: @AliAdlavaran unfortunately not..

Comment: What you want to improve here is search performance, so you should use `HashSet<Country>` as it has O(1) search performance, instead of O(n) for `List<Country>`. And implement `IEquatable<Country>` interface...

Comment: @Johnny I imagined... thanks

Comment: Have you done any profiling to see what's taking the most time? Using a HashSet or Dictionary instead of a List will probably make a small difference, but only if you've got tens of thousands of items. Is `GetCountryByDate` doing a database round-trip? If so, you'll have very slow performance with maybe a dozen or so dates, and no other optimization you make is going to make a perceivable difference: You need to find a way to get al the countries for those dates in a single round-trip. Can you share the code from GetCountryByDate so we can suggest a way to do that?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior is a method of a dll I cannot see that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are checking for new countries in `countries` list by `ISO` property.

Instead of looping the list for every new country (which is O(n<sup>2</sup>)), generate `HashSet<string>` for `ISO` property which will turn search algorithm into O(n).

```
var existedISOCodes = countries.Select(country => country.ISO).ToHashSet();

foreach (var date in dates)
{
    var newCountries = GetCountryByDate(date);

    foreach (var country in newCountries)
    {
        if (existedISOCodes.Add(country.iso))
        {
            countries.Add(new Country
            {
                Id = country.id,
                Name = country.name,
                ISO = country.iso,
                Link = country.id.ToString()
            });
        }
    }
}
```

`HashSet<T>.Add` method will try to add given value to the set and return `false` if value already exists.

If you are a fan of LINQ:

```
var existedISOCodes = countries.Select(country => country.ISO).ToHashSet();
var newCountries = 
    dates.SelectMany(date => GetCountryByDate(date))
         .Where(country => existedISOCodes.Add(country.ISO))
         .Select(country => 
         {
             return new Country
             {
                 Id = country.id,
                 Name = country.name,
                 ISO = country.iso,
                 Link = country.id.ToString()
             };
         });

countries.AddRange(newCountries);
```

But I assume actual performance bottleneck is `GetCountryByDate` method.
If this method accessing some external resources (database, webservices) and you are not able to get countries for all date in one requests, you probably can turn `GetCountryByDate` into asynchronous function then you will be able to get countries for all dates almost simultaneously

```
var newCountryTasks = dates.Select(date => GetCountryByDateAsync(date));
await Task.WhenAll(newCountryTasks);

var newCountries = 
    newCountryTasks.SelectMany(task => task.Result)
                   .Where(country => existedISOCodes.Add(country.ISO))
                   .Select(country => 
                   {
                       return new Country
                       {
                           Id = country.id,
                           Name = country.name,
                           ISO = country.iso,
                           Link = country.id.ToString()
                       };
                   });

countries.AddRange(newCountries);
```

Comment: woooa da benevento con furore :)